# For Loop through PictureBoxes WITHOUT an array on c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception, picturebox

```cs
char SideA = 'A';
char SideB = 'B';
int CPUPlayer = 1;
Test.Text = x.ToString();

if (difficulty == 1)
{ 
    if (CPUPlayer == 1)
    {

        string targetString = "";
        for (int side = 1; side <= 1; side++)
        {

            targetString = SideA.ToString();
            Test.Text = targetString.ToString();
            for (int game = 1; game < 25; game++)
            {
                targetString = game.ToString();
                for (int tile = 1; tile < 10; tile++)
                {
                    targetString = tile.ToString();
                    PictureBox target = (PictureBox)(this.Controls.Find(targetString, true))[0];
                    if (target.BackgroundImage == null)
                    {
                        target.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.smallo;
                        Test.Text = targetString.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to loop through prenamed PictureBoxes (Ex: A11,A12,A13....etc) to have them change background Images by using the loop through string to connect to the pictureboxes but I keep getting `Index is out of range` from the `PictureBox target = (PictureBox)(this.Controls.Find(targetString, true))[0];`

I'm not sure what to do to fix it. I'm very new to c# and coding in general so would be nice to know what I'm missing!

Comment: Apparently `this.Controls.Find(targetString, true)` is an empty array in some cases.

Comment: You need to break `PictureBox target = (PictureBox)(this.Controls.Find(targetString, true))[0]` into multiple statements and [look at the values in a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: Cache your images in an array instead of using them from `Resources` like that.  You are needlessly creating numerous objects when a single one will do and will lead to leaks

Answer (score 1):

To help you find the problem change

```
PictureBox target = (PictureBox)(this.Controls.Find(targetString, true))[0];
```

to

```
var found = this.Controls.Find(targetString, true);

if(found == null || found.Length < 1 ) {
  throw new Exception("Picture not found")
}
```

After that, set a breakpoint in the `throw` line and find out why the picture was not found.

Comment: Sorry bout that string, I edited it out,and it  was just in there from testing that i forgot to take out before i posted this  my bad :(

Comment: Your comment helped me realize what was wrong thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So turns out it was just my `.ToString();` logic that was just flat out wrong and the string was coming out as a picturebox that didn't exist. This is the code that works:

```
            if (difficulty == 1)
        { 
            if (CPUPlayer == 1)
            {

                string targetString = "";
                for (int side = 1; side <= 1; side++)
                { 
                    for (int game = 1; game < 25; game++)
                    {

                        for (int tile = 1; tile < 10; tile++)
                        {
                            targetString = SideA;
                            targetString += game.ToString();
                            targetString += tile.ToString();
                            Test.Text = targetString.ToString();
                            PictureBox target = (PictureBox)(this.Controls.Find(targetString, true))[0];
```